# error when trying to use StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

hello people get this error when trying to use QuerySnapshot

```
   child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream:
                  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('messages').snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                  case ConnectionState.none:
                  case ConnectionState.waiting:
                    // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
                    return Center(
                      // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                  default:
                    List<DocumentSnapshot> documents =
                        snapshot.data!.docs.reversed.toList();
                    return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: documents.length,
                        reverse: true,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return ListTile(
                            title: Text(documents[index]['text']),
                          );
                        });
                }
              },
            ),
```

Exception caught by widgets library
The following _CastError was thrown building StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot<Object?>, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>>#b7dc5):Null check operator used on a null value

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint on the Title line?

Answer (score 0):

Another point is to check if your list has items and if the firebase path is correct